# documnent.createElement() not displaying

Tags: jquery, createelement

I am attempting to write my own comment script by using javascript to take in the value of the entered fields and then create a div with that information inside it using document.createElement(*Element*). What's odd is that when I hit the submit form button, it calls the javascript function which appends the div to the DOM, but then immediately deletes it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"      type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>

.newComment{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

</style>

<body onload="addElement()">
<form>
    <input type="text" name="user" style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 15px;" placeholder="Username" id="username"></input>
    <br />
    <br />
    <textarea type="text" name="comment" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; font-size: 15px;" placeholder="Comment" id="comment"></textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" style="float: left; margin-right: 15%;" onclick="addElement()"></input>
</form>

<script>

document.body.onload = addElement;

function addElement () { 
  // create a new div element 
  // and give it some content 
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
  var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!"); 
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div. 

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
}

/*function send(){
    var name = document.getElementById("username").value
    var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value
    console.log(name, comment)

    var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
    $(newDiv).attr('class', 'newComment')
    var divClass = $(newDiv).attr("class")
    console.log(divClass)

    $(newDiv).appendTo("body")
    $(".newComment").html(name)
}*/


</script>
</body>
```

Can someone please explain why this happens with both the uncommented and the commented function? I have read the jQuery API and it claims that this shouldn't happen, but it has happened every time I have used the submit button.

Thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't add the event handler twice I think. It might end up running twice...

Comment: @nus: There is no risk for that, the second will replace the first. It's just pointless to add it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a form is submitted the browser sends a POST request to the action of the form. In your case you do not have an action attribute so the browser sends a POST for the current url and effectively refreshes the page (so your scripts run again and start over).

You can prevent the form from submitting by returning false from the click handler:

```
onclick="addElement(); return false;"
```

Although it would be better to remove that inline Javascript altogether (it's a bad idea to mix HTML and Javascript) and bind it like this:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click( function ( ) {
    addElement();
    return false;
} );
```

It would be even better to give that input an `id` and select it that way, so that you can safely add other input elements to the page without unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You have included jquery in your page:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=submit]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var div = $("<div>");
        div.text("Hi there and greetings!");
        $("body").append(div);
    });
});
```

Comment: was thinking the same thing, but it doesn't really answer the question as to why it didn't work. It should be also possible to do what they wanted without jquery.

Comment: @nus Yes your right but the OP has added jquery label to the post and has added the jquery link in his code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the element goes away is that the page is reloaded. The default behaviour for the submit button is to send the form to the server, so after the element has been added to the page, the form is posted to the server and the page reloads.

Return `false` from the event handler to prevent the default action:

```
onclick="addElement();return false;"
```